# Check if field is integer in select

Tags: firebird, firebird2.1

I'm trying to determine whether the content of a field is an integer value.

In firebird 2.5 there is "similar to", but this wasn't available in 2.1 yet.

Comment: You could try to find a UDF that does this (or write your own).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.

For now I'll go with:

```
substring(fieldname from 1 for 1) > '0' and 
substring(fieldname from 1 for 1) < '9'
```

Answer (score 0):

This procedure using error handling, returns field value as is if contents is integer, otherwise return 0

```
SET TERM ^ ;

create or alter procedure INT_CHECK (
    IN_STR varchar(100))
returns (
    ORESULT integer)
as
BEGIN
  /* because WHEN works for the entire block use a separate BEGIN..END*/
  begin  -- START OF BLOCK
  oresult = cast(:in_str as integer);
  when any do
      begin
        oresult = 0;
      end
  end    -- END OF BLOCK
  suspend;
END^

SET TERM ; ^
```